# ProviderException when using a custom output cache provider RedisOutputCacheProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, outputcache, stackexchange.redis

I have installed the nuget package `Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider` for use with Azure Web App running on multiple server instances following the instructions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798898.aspx and are receiving the following error:

```
When using a custom output cache provider like 'MyRedisOutputCache', only the following expiration policies and cache features are supported:  file dependencies, absolute expirations, static validation callbacks and static substitution callbacks.
```

The configuration setting is as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
    <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" 
             type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" 
             port="1234" 
             host="[my host]" 
             accessKey="[my access key]" 
             ssl="true" />
      </providers>
    </outputCache>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

I've tried setting the `connectionString` to a valid StackExchange.Redis connection string instead of setting the individual port/host etc... but still receive the same error.

We also have the `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider` running in the same web app using the same settings with no issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? We are also having this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using the RedisOutputCacheProvider with secured controller actions which employ some flavor of the AuthorizeAttribute appear to be causing the exception. It works fine for AllowAnonymous actions. The below may help:

[Why can't I combine [Authorize] and [OutputCache] attributes when using Azure cache (.NET MVC3 app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682635/why-cant-i-combine-authorize-and-outputcache-attributes-when-using-azure-ca)