# How to use PageOutPut Caching in MVC with Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, authorize

We are using [Authorize] attribute on base controller which redirects each unauthenticated user to log in page and grants the access to every authenticated user which is working as expected. We are also using Azure manged cache service /distributed cache service to store certain data. Now we are trying to use the Page Output caching in some places but getting the exception below

*When using a custom output cache provider like 'AFCacheOutputCacheProvider', only the following expiration policies and cache features are supported: file dependencies, absolute expirations, static validation callbacks and static substitution callbacks. 
at System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.InsertResponse(String cachedVaryKey, CachedVary cachedVary, String rawResponseKey, CachedRawResponse rawResponse, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime absExp, TimeSpan slidingExp) at System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)*

I did search around this and found many posts mentioning that never use Authorize attribute with page output caching because of the logical reason that caching will not let you see the content of another users. 
Here are few linked which we have already refereed, you can check those [here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/29/asp-net-mvc-tip-40-don-t-cache-pages-that-require-authentication) and here -  [Why can't I combine [Authorize] and [OutputCache] attributes when using Azure cache (.NET MVC3 app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682635/why-cant-i-combine-authorize-and-outputcache-attributes-when-using-azure-ca)

Isn't it the common requirement in applications where you have action methods protected with authorize attribute but you still want to cache the output of action methods (varying by params)?